# Bash was overwritten. Using Dash, apt-get --reinstall install bash returns an error

Tags: bash, kali-linux

So, I overwrote `/bin/bash` with a stupid bash script by accident. My previous question can be found below. It was recommended that I create a new one to deal with a problem that arose. To recap, I was able to use the GUI to change my default terminal to dash, where I can run commands. Now, I am attempting to reinstall bash so that I can change my default terminal back. As previously stated, I'm running `apt-get --reinstall install` bash, which should reinstall it. However, it returns an error:

```
    reading package lists...
Building dependency tree...
Reading state information...
The following additional packages will be installed:
  bash-completion
Suggested packages:
  bash-doc
The following packages will be upgraded:
  bash bash-completion
2 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 2128 not upgraded.
2 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 0 B/1,605 kB of archives.
After this operation, 673 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] (Reading database ... 
(Reading database ... 5%
(Reading database ... 10%
(Reading database ... 15%
(Reading database ... 20%
(Reading database ... 25%
(Reading database ... 30%
(Reading database ... 35%
(Reading database ... 40%
(Reading database ... 45%
(Reading database ... 50%
(Reading database ... 55%
(Reading database ... 60%
(Reading database ... 65%
(Reading database ... 70%
(Reading database ... 75%
(Reading database ... 80%
(Reading database ... 85%
(Reading database ... 90%
(Reading database ... 95%
(Reading database ... 100%
(Reading database ... 307792 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../archives/bash_4.4-5_amd64.deb ...
dpkg (subprocess): unable to execute old pre-removal script (/var/lib/dpkg/info/bash.prerm): No such file or directory
dpkg: warning: subprocess old pre-removal script returned error exit status 2
dpkg: trying script from the new package instead ...
dpkg (subprocess): unable to execute new pre-removal script (/var/lib/dpkg/tmp.ci/prerm): No such file or directory
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/bash_4.4-5_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 subprocess new pre-removal script returned error exit status 2
dpkg (subprocess): unable to execute installed post-installation script (/var/lib/dpkg/info/bash.postinst): No such file or directory
dpkg: error while cleaning up:
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 2
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/bash_4.4-5_amd64.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Also, `dpkg --configure bash` says that it had and error processing the package, and that bash is "in a very bad inconsistent state; you should reinstall it before attempting configuration."

The distribution I an running is Kali 2.2 rolling, and I already know I'm gonna get a lot of hate for this one because if anything, overwriting bash is a mistake.

New Post, as recommeded by @Philippos. Link to old post is [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/398543/what-are-the-contents-of-bin-bash-and-what-do-i-do-if-i-accidentally-overwrote)

Comment: Related: [Why is Kali Linux so hard to set up? Why won't people help me?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/399626/why-is-kali-linux-so-hard-to-set-up-why-wont-people-help-me)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The problem is that the bash prerm script uses bash so it fails to run causing the whole reinstallation to fail.

There are multiple ways you could get around this:

1) 
The bash prerm script on my systems (Debian unstable & Debian stable) is incredibly simple and does not need bash to run. So simply edit `/var/lib/dpkg/info/bash.prerm` and change the first line from `#! /bin/bash` to `#! /bin/sh`. Also ensure that `/bin/sh` is not pointing at `bash` (`ls -l /bin/sh`). If it is, you likely have `/bin/dash` installed, so try editing the prerm file to use that instead.

2) Delete the prerm file and re-install. The prerm file does nothing important in version 4.4-5 on Debian, so you could just get rid of the prerm file and try to reinstall.

3) You can extract `/bin/bash` from the `.deb` archive already downloaded. You can see the path in your output: `/var/cache/apt/archives/bash_4.4-5_amd64.deb`. This is an `ar(1)` archive containing three files:

- `debian-binary`
- `control-tar.gz`
- `data.tar.xz`

Note that the `data.tar` file might not be a `xz` compressed file - there are other formats - gzip, bzip, etc. I'm going to assume it is an `xz` file, but if not, you can replace that suffix and zcat program appropriately.

You can see the contents of the `.deb` file by running:

```
$ ar t /var/cache/apt/archives/bash_4.4-5_amd64.deb
debian-binary
control.tar.gz
data.tar.xz
```

You can see the contents of the `data.tar.xz` file by running:

```
$ ar p /var/cache/apt/archives/bash_4.4-5_amd64.deb data.tar.xz | xzcat | tar tvf -
...
./bin/bash
...
```

You can extract `/bin/bash` from that:

```
$ cd /tmp
$ ar p /var/cache/apt/archives/bash_4.4-5_amd64.deb data.tar.xz | xzcat | tar xvf - ./bin/bash
```

Since you did that from `/tmp`. you will now have file `/tmp/bin/bash`. You can copy that back into `/bin` and overwrite bash again, but this time with some good content.

There are dpkg tools that you can use to manipulate `.deb` files, but since that they are simple archives, I find it easier to remember how to use `ar(1)` and `tar(1)` as opposed to dpkg-specific options.

Comment: Your first method--changing`#! /bin/bash` to `#! /bin/sh` in `/var/lib/dpkg/info/bash.prerm`--is fast, easy, and effective. Kali Linux is a derivative of Debian, where `/bin/sh` [has been a symlink to `dash`](https://wiki.debian.org/Shell) for quite some years now, so no extra steps are necessary. (Anyway, [the OP's previous post](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/398543/11938) says they restarted, and they would've gotten way more errors if `/bin/sh` wasn't working.) I don't have a Kali system but I tested this on Debian 9.2; I would be very surprised if it were not equally effective on Kali.

Comment: One could even temporarily symlink `dash` to `/bin/bash` (avoids having to find + modify the install script shebangs). The link will  get overwritten by the real `bash`. (I did it once just to see...)

Comment: Thanks for the long and detailed post! using the 2 last commands (ar p) I get the following errors [tar: this does not look like a tar archive   tar: ./bin/bash: Not found in archive    tar: exiting with failure status due to previous errors] thanks for all the help!

Comment: @GarrukApex: Sorry I did not copy the commands from my terminal properly. I left of the "data.tar.xz" argument to the `ar` command. I have edited my answer. Could you try it again?

Comment: Wow that worked! Thank you so much for your help!